# Is it possible to use VPN for only one Program?

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to use VPN connection for only one program and the rest of the traffic go through the local network?

More specifically, I am using the Official Cisco Client.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/644130/41337 which addreses the issue on GNU/Linux.

Comment: If your application supports proxy, this might be helpful: https://blog.jithinpavithran.com/content/?article=docked-vpn

Answer (score 5):

You could install a virtual machine and run the cisco vpn together with your program of choice on the virtual machine while keeping you normal working environment connected normally.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the only thing you can do is configuring a split tunnel based on a policy (e.g. target IP range/mask, see [the examples at Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2284/products_configuration_example09186a0080094b02.shtml)). If your program is only communicating with that IP, that would have the same effect for your purpose. However, this must be configured on the VPN-server side by the administrator.

Comment: I guess I should of specified.  I really need a client side solution.  I do not control the vpn server

Answer (score 3):

On Windows®, it is possible to use VPN to communicate only with one or few hosts by specifying needed route entries (see "route /?"), but this works on per remote host basis.
On linux/freebsd it is possible to start program with non-default routing table, so it does the trick: all applications use default routing table and traffic goes to local network and one specific program uses other routing table and traffic goes throw VPN.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Cisco VPN client and go to Preferences. Uncheck "Enable local LAN access (if configured". For myself, I am using a remote desktop connection to a remote location and my local browser resolves to my local IP.

I am using the "Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a free pc or a VM, configure that PC to dial the VPN connection, and install a free based proxy server (in my experience they usually limit you to 3 users).  I feel that this is okay for home use, then you configure the application to use the proxy.  Most network based applications usually have proxy settings.

This will allow your normal traffic go out your gateway and the application will take the way of the proxy, which happens to be connect to the vpn.

Comment: Forgive me, but at the moment I can't see how that answers the question.  In addition, is there any chance you could do without the txt-speak?

Comment: @MadHatter, this is why we have an 'edit' function on stackexchange.

Comment: Oddly, I was aware of that (and have approved your edit).  However, life would be easier if authors didn't use it, as [the help documents](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) recommend they don't.  My first point still stands.

Comment: If the application allows the user to specify a proxy then this may be a good solution, but i think this data would still be going through the vpn.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an old article about Microsoft's "Direct Connect"](http://blog.nextxpert.com/2008/05/28/direct-connect-death-of-the-dmz-becoming-reality/) which I've heard of in use recently.  I haven't found any documentation links yet but you might if you're motivated.

As I understand it it's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the routing for only one (or a selection of) ports to go through the VPN with other network access to go normal.

Setting say one browser to use the VPN (on port 80) and all the others to use direct is trickier

Answer (score 0):

For not tech-savvy users best bet would be to use a VPN application that has this feature built-in. Expressvpn surely has it on windows and I think nord on mobile apps. https://www.hlplanet.com/how-to-use-vpn-for-only-one-application/